# Run the same Job simultaneously with different parameters in Pentaho PDI

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I developed a Job that receives the Customer Id as a parameter and loads the connection data from the database, so as not to have to duplicate codes and have a greater effort in maintenance.

However, when executing the Job simultaneously through a main Job, both the parameters and the variables with the scope to be of the current Job, keep the value of the last Job started.

If you trigger the Job through Kitchen via command lines, it works perfectly, isolating the variables. However, it is extremely slow and consumes much more resource from the machine, due to having several instances of Pentaho running, even limiting the JVM memory usage to 2GB, being an 8GB machine with 4 vCPUs. I tested with 3 jobs running simultaneously.

```
I would like to know if anyone has had a similar problem and how they resolved it.
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run job simultaneously, sequencely run the job may be more effective. Check the job Options "Execute every input row", and may solve your question.

Comment: I need to update the clients every 1 hour, so it would be a problem to run them one after the other, due to the sum total of the time for each one, it can exceed the update window time